# PodDisruptionBudget not effective on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I wanted to test PDB policy effectiveness on local minikube setup.

- Created a NGINX deployment with replicas=5.
- Created a PDB for NGINX to minAvailable=2. Shows AllowedDisruptions=3.
- Updated deployment with replicas=0.
- All NGINX pods were killed and deployment showed 0/0 despite PDB being in effect.
- Now PDB shows AllowedDisruptions=0.

Why was PDB not respected and stopped from killing all the pods?

Is this is a testable scenario or my understanding of pod eviction which respects PDB not correct?
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to test PDB is by [draining a node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/).**Updating the replica count is not considered a disruption**. PDB kicks in when a pod is evicted using the eviction API which happens while draining a node.

Here is the list of involuntary disruptions

1. a hardware failure of the physical machine backing the node
2. cluster administrator deletes VM (instance) by mistake
3. cloud provider or hypervisor failure makes VM disappear
4. a kernel panic
5. the node disappears from the cluster due to cluster network partition
   eviction of a pod due to the node being out-of-resources.

Here is the list of voluntary disruptions

1. deleting the deployment or other controller that manages the pod
2. updating a deployment’s pod template causing a restart
3. directly deleting a pod (e.g. by accident)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-disruption-budgets-work

Comment: There are a few other places that check it like resource evictions but drains are indeed that vast majority of the use case.